# dplyr: difference between specific rows

Tags: r, dplyr

Using this data.frame

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text = c("
                 id measured    simulated
Site1   9.10    9.20
Site2   126.00  129.02
Site3   1.00    1.15
Site4   84.50   85.77
Site5   115.60  119.30
Site6   12.10   12.26
Site7   163.10  167.18
Site8   74.10   75.51
Site9   19.20   19.74
Site10  74.80   77.12
Site11  287.80  300.46
Site12  13.40   13.76
Site13  283.60  288.70
Site14  475.70  495.68
Site15  741.20  779.74
Site16  2215.10 2398.95 "), header = T)
```

The first 10 sites are ***independent*** (don't include any site upstream). But the last 6 sites are ***dependent*** as they include one or more sites as shown below.

I want to create two new columns `measured_diff` and `simulated_diff`. The values in these columns will be ***independent*** which means for the last six sites, the upstream site(s) will be subtracted from any dependent sites as shown below.

**FINAL RESULT**

It should be like this

```
#       id measured simulated measured_diff simulated_diff
#1   Site1      9.1      9.20           9.1           9.20  #independent
#2   Site2    126.0    129.02         126.0         129.02  #independent
#3   Site3      1.0      1.15           1.0           1.15  #independent
#4   Site4     84.5     85.77          84.5          85.77  #independent
#5   Site5    115.6    119.30         115.6         119.30  #independent
#6   Site6     12.1     12.26          12.1          12.26  #independent
#7   Site7    163.1    167.18         163.1         167.18  #independent
#8   Site8     74.1     75.51          74.1          75.51  #independent
#9   Site9     19.2     19.74          19.2          19.74  #independent
#10 Site10     74.8     77.12          74.8          77.12  #independent
#11 Site11    287.8    300.46         161.8         171.44  #site11 - site2
#12 Site12     13.4     13.76          12.4          12.61  #site12 - site3
#13 Site13    283.6    288.70         199.1         202.94  #site13 - site4 
#14 Site14    475.7    495.68         298.2         313.59  #site14-(site3+site7+site12)
#15 Site15    741.2    779.74         280.4         309.47  #site15-(site1+site8+site9+site10+site13)
#16 Site16   2215.1   2398.95         582.7         691.51  #site16-(site5+site6+site11+site14+site15)
```

I will appreciate any suggestions how to do this in R?

Comment: This seems like a custom calculation instead of any patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @akrun said, there is no real pattern here, so you can do something like this:

```
df$measured.diff = with(df, c(measured[1:10], 
                              measured[11:13]-measured[2:4],
                              measured[14]-sum(measured[c(3,7,12)]),
                              measured[15]-sum(measured[c(1,8,9,10,13)]),
                              measured[16]-sum(measured[c(5,6,11,14,15)])))
```

And then you can do the same for `df$simulated.diff`

Alternatively, since you are doing the same custom calculation more than once, it makes sense to create your own custom function.

```
custom_diff = function(vec){
  c(vec[1:10],
    vec[11:13]-vec[2:4],
    vec[14]-sum(vec[c(3,7,12)]),
    vec[15]-sum(vec[c(1,8,9,10,13)]),
    vec[16]-sum(vec[c(5,6,11,14,15)]))
}

df$measured.diff = custom_diff(df$measured)
df$simulated.diff = custom_diff(df$simulated)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help.